# Python programming repeatedly "Killed"

Tags: python, virtualbox, archlinux

I'm working on a predictive text program that uses an entire book to fit and test a Random Forest Classifier. Initially I was sampling a small amount of data points from my Pandas dataframe just for testing; however if I try to use the whole data set, the program runs for a few minutes and returns "Killed."

Running Python 3.7.3 on Arch Linux via VirtualBox with a Windows 10 host. The virtual machine is allocated 10 gigs of RAM, so I don't think that should be the problem.

```
 #vectorize
 tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 10)
 tfidf_result = tfidf.fit_transform(df['input']).toarray()
 tfidf_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_result, columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())
 tfidf_df.index = df.index
 df = pd.concat([df, tfidf_df], axis = 1)

 #split data into train and test - including 'input' in x so it can be connected w/ output
 columns = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'output']

 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[columns], df['output'], test_size = 0.2)

 #random forest classifier
 columns = [c for c in x_train.columns if c != 'input']

 rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
 rf.fit(x_train[columns], y_train)

 #predict
 predictions = rf.predict(x_test[columns])
```

Comment: What is the size of the data set? Did you check the memory usage of the process?

Comment: The dataframe has around 25,000 rows. I should note that sometimes instead of getting the "Killed" output, I get "Could not allocate x bytes" where x is generally around 1 gig, which is way less than is allocated to the vm.